# Cannot see cells when I have Two UITableViews in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First of all this is not a duplicate as I have read through very similarly titled questions but they do not give me the correct answer!

So what I have done is:

First of all create a Table View with 13 unique (contain different buttons) prototype cells where the table views content is "Dynamic Prototypes". I then created a UITableViewCell class called `blurCell`.

I can see the new/second `UITableView` but there are no cells within it?

I currently have (for the first UITableView) the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  25;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
}
```

But I did this because I was using a .xib for this table.

Do I need this kind of code for the new/second `UITableView` as I have done everything manually in the storyboard?

Please help?

---

In the ViewController.m (`ImagesTableViewController`) that contains these two tables I have the code:

```
@interface ImagesTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Which is linked to both tables

Comment: Each table view must have its data source. Dynamic prototypes just help you set up different cells.

Comment: @LeoNatan can you look at my update in my question

Comment: Yes, you need that kind of code for both tables. You will need if-else clauses in the data source methods to differentiate between the two tables.

Comment: @rdelmar May you help me with that?

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: the `if-else clauses in the data source methods to differentiate between the two tables`

Comment: I am just going to test removing the conection outlets of the old table

Comment: even when I remove the outlets of the old table it doesn't work?

Comment: @rdelmar even if I delete the old table the cells do not show!

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't help us help you -- what are you seeing when your app runs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56784/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-maximilian).

Answer (score 1):

Each tableView should be declared as its own property with the delegate/data source set to self most likely in viewDidLoad

You need to do something like this for the delegate/data source methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(tableView==firstTableView) return  25;
  else if(tableView==secondTableView) return  2;
  else return  15;
return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
if(tableView==firstTableView) return  1;
  else if(tableView==secondTableView) return  2;
 return 0;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{...}
```

Comment: the thing is, is that both tables are running at the same time. So this gives errors

Comment: Can you show me your implementation of these three methods. What is the error you receive?